# Cant seem to open mysql.h in my visual studio project

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

I'm currently trying to connect a MySQL server to my C++ project so I can insert & delete it from the project. I've downloaded the SQL server added the included directories and lib files in the project property settings. I copied the .dll files into the executable directory. I changed the configuration manager from debug to release.

But when I try:

```
#include <mysql.h>
```

It says it cannot open the source file. Would anyone know why this is.

**Include and lib path,dll in executable directory & MySQL.h in the directory in project properties **

[image: Include path]

[image: Lib path]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Normally putting it in  "Project PropertiesVC++ Directories/Include Directories" should do the trick. Use "Configuration: All configurations"

Comment: ya recently tried the all config approach and it results in the same outcome

Comment: well as a workaround you can always specify the full path just to get it building and then figure that out later

Comment: Make sure in the property window that you're also setting the correct active platform. E.g. if you're compiling for x86, make sure it's set to x86 in the property window.

Comment: i added what the configuration manager looks like to the question